# GPUImage examples producing errors in Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, gpuimage

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm trying to learn Brad Larson's **GPUImage** by going through the examples.

I'm using **Xcode 7.2** and very few of the examples work out of the box.

I found out how to fix this error`"-fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0"` just by changing the deployment target.

But I can't figure this one out:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'
```

I've tried several answers given on stackOverflow, but none of them have worked.  To narrow it down, I really want to see how the colorObjectTracking example works.

Comment: there should be a root view controller set while launching.

Comment: As I said, I'm fairly new to programming - I've tried several solutions for doing that.   They only produced more errors.  Here is the examples:
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

I need to know the exact steps to make the colorObjectTracking example work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `rootViewController` property of the main window isn't set before method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` finishes.

To fix that you have to change the body of this method (it can be found in `ColorTrackingAppDelegate.m` file) to the one presented below:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

     self.window.rootViewController = [[ColorTrackingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
}
```

**Update:**
I submitted Pull Request which fixes issue in `ColorObjectTracking` example project that is the reason of your problems. You can find it [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/pull/2195).